# Still use Hibernate with Spring?

Tags: performance, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, development-environment

OLD POST

I am planning to new project with spring 3.2 ,but can't see any active example via spring 3.2 data for hibernate  .

Let say I can configure it myself but question is spring source has plan to broke hibernate support?
Or  Is spring jpa better choice? Why still they use hibernate validator?
How is development time? does we should register entity each time? **Does eclipse jpa validator validating that entity for long times again?**

Is it reliable ? I saw interesting commit log in spring data git such "removing Serializable because it creates a lot of warnings" ! on BaseEntity.java see git https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/model

Comment: Have you realized that one usually asks one question at a time at StackOverflow? This is not a question…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there is a Spring Data JPA project. JPA is a Java standard for entity persistence, but it needs a persistence provider. I have no numbers, but I would say the leading persistence provider in the Java space is Hibernate.

So Spring *Data* has decided to make it easier to use the JPA standard and decoupled itself from Hibernate directly and specifically. But Hibernate is still around through the Spring Data JPA abstraction.

Note however that the original Spring Framework does indeed have direct Hibernate [support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/).